# Network? or router? problem

Tags: networking

I have two computers networked through a Netgear WG914 router which is connected to an Ipstar satellite modem via the RG47 LAN connector.   The main computer is running Windows 7 Pro 64bit and the secondary computer is running Windows 7 Home Edition 32bit.   On occasion there is a loss of internet connection usually on the main computer, often followed by a loss on the secondary comuter.  Not, however, always the case.  Windows troubleshooter, naturally, is about as much use as a politician in government.......NONE.   There appears to be no problem with the ISP bad as it is and often the connection will be remade without any help from me.
The difference in the OS's is not of any relevance since I had this problem before I changed over to Windows 7.
Not being a nerd when it comes to networking I wonder if anyone has any constructive suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Does the problem occur if you connect a computer directly to the modem?  If not, it could be indicating that your router is causing problems.

Another solution is to connect your computer together and use Internet Connection Sharing, and connect 1 of the computer directly to the modem.  If this works then again the router may be to blame.

Perhaps see if you can find a firmware update for the router.

Answer (score 0):

I'm willing to bet, given the information present already, that it is something with the router (most connectivity issues are with a home router and not the ISP). If you get failure on one machine and not another, then there is no problem with your ISP. You can of course test this by directly connecting to your modem and setting your computers to repeatedly ping your DNS servers for a period of about an hour or so and you should never see lower than about 3% loss (granted with satellite, it may be different, but you really shouldn't stick with that connection if it is normal to see loss over 3%).

Swap out all your network cables. Test with a different router. Test with other computers if possible. Note where the common failure point is. Again, I think you'll find the router is the common point of failure in these tests.